# Redirect all specific urls to the previous folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, uri, redirect, virtualhost

I have a site with more than 35,000 pages on WordPress but the problem is that I didn't know that automatically a "feed" page was created for each page/categories/posts.

I have disabled this feature but I would like to redirect all these feed pages this way:

```
https://$url/$uri/feed
```

to

```
https://$url/$uri/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your 35,000 pages may not have been indexed by search engines. You might just want to add a RewriteRule and permanently redirect those indexed pages back to their original URLs.

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/zYyBBc/1) would simply do that:

[image]

#### Graph

If you wish to know how that expression works, this graph shows that:

[image]

#### Code

Then, you might want to add a code similar to this to your `.htaccess`, then maybe restart your apache:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

and clear your browser cache every time that you modify your `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*)\/feed$ $1\/$ [L,R=301,QSA]
</IfModule>
```